# Protractor tests are timing out due to async call back not invoked with angular 2 App SPA

Tags: angular, protractor, jasmine2.0

We are building SPA with angular cli, We are to verify controls on log in page (username,password and login) but after login/redirect to another component i am getting error message

> "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

for any kind of action like clicking log out button or verify user label. we have only one app.com.html with redirecting with `another.com.html`

Here is my sample spec code

```
beforeAll(() => {
loginPage = new LoginPage();
loginPage.navigateTo();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/');
loginPage.login(testData.validAgentID, testData.validDeviceID);
browser.waitForAngular();
userPage = new UserPage();
// browser.angularAppRoot('sp-app');
});
beforeEach(() => {
//
});
it('should be able to see Logout button at the bottom', function (done) {
expect(userPage.getLogoutButton().getText()).toEqual('logout'); Failing
done();
});

it('should be able to see Logout button at the bottom', () => {
expect(userPage.getLogoutButton().getText()).toEqual('logout'); Failing
});

it('should be able to see Logout button at the bottom', () => {
userPage.getLogoutButton().getText().then((txt)=> {
expect(txt).toEqual('logout');   Failing
});
});

beforeAll(() => {
loginPage = new LoginPage();
loginPage.navigateTo();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/');
browser.waitForAngular();
userPage = new UserPage();
// browser.angularAppRoot('sp-app');
});
beforeEach(() => {
//
});
it('should be able to verify title', () => {
expect(userPage.getTitle.getText()).toEqual('My App');   This is working fine
});

Tried all possible options to make my verification 

"@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.32.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.1",
"protractor": "^5.1.1",
```

Comment: can you clean up formatting of post as well as provide the userPage.getLogoutButton() code?

Comment: Let me start with one basic suggestion .. did you try increasing the Jasmine Timeout setting value and see if that helps ... `defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000`

Comment: @adityareddy, I have 30sec defaulttimeout interval set up protractor.config  please find log out code  getLogoutButton() {
     return element(by.id('btnLogout'));
    //return this.logOutButtonElement;
  }